# filter out images by file name

Tags: jquery

I currently have the following jQuery snipplet that will find images in a specific div and exclude ones with a specific class:

```
var postImgs = $('#primary img');
var classes = new Array(".skip", ".block", ".ignore");    

postImgs.each(function (){  
   if(!$(this).is(classes.join(", "))) {
      //Do Something
   }
});
```

What I also need to do is check for specific file names to not apply the function to either.  So I tried something... but it didn't work:

```
postImgs.not('img[src$="uniquefile.jpg"]').each(function (){ }
```

Even then, I would much rather prefer to be able to provide an array of file names, like I can with my classes .

So how can I also specify an array of file names to skip, in addition to keeping the classes filter I am already employing?  That way I can just do something like this:

```
var fileNames = new Array("uniquefile.jpg", "somename.png", "anotherfile.gif");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in the selector

```
var filenames = ['google.com','msn.com','yahoo.com'];

$('img').not('[src$="' + filenames.join('"],[src$="') + '"]'); // <-- gets images that are not specified in array
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DF9rx/

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileNames = new Array("uniquefile.jpg", "somename.png", "anotherfile.gif");

postImgs.each(function (idx, elem){  
    var ok = true;
    $.each(fileNames, function(i, filename) {
        if (elem.src.indexOf(filename) != -1) ok = false;
    });

    if (ok) {
        //image file is not excluded, do something
    }

});
```

or you can filter the selector:

```
var fileNames = new Array("uniquefile.jpg", "somename.png", "anotherfile.gif");

postImgs.filter(function() {
    return $.inArray(this.src, fileNames); //requires exact match
});
```